# Strange links requested from MSIE

Tags: javascript, html

we're running a shop that currently has several 100 visitors a day.
Now and then some strange urls are requested, like `/shop/public/ww/script/jqueryE 7` or `/shop/public/css/print/zkagShntLink4` etc.

The problem is, that those links are neither generated by our application nor do they exist.
We also sometimes have links containing portions of html like `/shop/public/ww/script/cufon/Rotis_SemiSerif_Std_4> Notepad </span></a> <a id=`.

From our apache access.log it seems like it's always an IE 7 or 8 who calls those links.
However, we cannot reproduce that in order to track the source of the problem.

My questions now are: 
Did anybody experience a similar problem?
Does anybody have any idea on what might be the problem or what we might look after? (We suspect it might be a speed problem and thus IE might get confused).

Another note: often the DOM is modified using Javascript and thus Javascript is required. If a user disables Javascript a modal dialog is displayed telling him to enable Javascript. So I'd assume Javascript is enabled in all those cases.

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your javascript auto-generate links on the client-side at all?  It's entirely possible that IE7/8 is parsing the javascript differently from the other browsers and generating incorrect links.

Otherwise, I'd guess it's a spambot or some such trying to probe your app.  But I think this is less likely, since the words "jqueryE 7" appear in the link -- something you wouldn't normally expect from a spambot.  Hard to say without actually poring over the data and your code.

Comment: Our javascript does indeed at times generate links, but normally no autogenerated ones. The problem is generally not the links to other pages but links to additional resources like CSS or JS files, and those are not generated by Javascript.

Comment: Oh and yes, we also doubt it's a spambot since those requests are quite rare compared to the number of visits and in most cases there's quite a long time between two of them (like several minutes to several hours).

Comment: Well it looks like something's getting garbled. The second link you provided looks like a tag somewhere that is missing the terminating double-quote in its href attribute.  I can't tell where it is, or what link it is (maybe even in your CSS), but you're definitely missing an end-quote somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for that info, I'll look for that. Unfortunately there is some Javascript library (cufon and jqtransform) messing with the dom (it's code we got from a partner who designed the page). And we can't reproduce that ourselves with IE 7 or IE 8, so I'd assume it's not something that is always missing.